# How To add WCF service reference for the duplex service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, webservice-client

I have a WCF service with callbacks. I want to create a client, BUT I want to do that automatically using "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio. I'm able to discover the service and add it. I can update service reference as well. So it's there. The problem is with creating a client out of it.

If the service name is (in service references) **"MyService",** then creating a client for a normal (non-callback) service would be:

```
var myService = new MyServiceClient();
var data = myService.GetData();
myService.Close();
```

But How can I do that if the service implements Callback interface?
I have to add context as a parameter for the Client, like this:

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(????);
var myService = new MyServiceClient(context);
var data = myService.GetData();
myService.Close();
```

but! I have to pass a client that implements callback interface into `InstanceContext`. Is there a way to quickly add client for the wcf service with callbacks?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a callback handler:

```
public class MyServiceCallbackHandler : IMyServiceCallback
{
    public void Result(Data data)
    {
    }
}
```

and pass it to `InstanceContext`:

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new MyServiceCallbackHandler());
var myService = new MyServiceClient(context);
var data = myService.GetData();
myService.Close();
```